# Flask: How to send this url (http://localhost:5088/detail_G1/update?time_i=1&time_r=0.25&more...parameters total=12) to call in next function

Tags: python, http, flask

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for

import os
import json
import pandas as pd

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def main_page():
    return render_template('home.html')


@app.route('/get_some', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def get_some():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        time_i = request.form.get('time_i')
        # ...more total=12parameters

        return redirect(url_for('some_update', time_i=time_i, # ...more total=12parameters))

    return render_template("some.html")


@app.route('/some/update')
def some_update():
    time_i = request.args.get('time_i')
    # ...more total=12parameters

    return render_template('update/some_new.html',  # ...more total=12parameters)


@app.route('/some/update', methods=('GET', 'POST'))
def post_new():
    calls_df = pd.read_html(some_update())  # HERE IS MY Mistake!
    print(calls_df)

    # ...other code...


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, port=5088)
```

> It's not worked, because read the URL(/some/update), BUT without all
>   12   parameters which I need for Pandas and return all data with value
>   None.
>       Please help, if you know, because I don't found relevant information.
>       Thank you!

Comment: Hey Vladyslav, we'll need more information to be able to help out, including what you're trying to do, and what steps we need to take to reproduce the problem. Optimally, you should give some code that we can run to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hi Jose! Thank you very much for your answer, but we found we create solution for app. 
We add - global url = None in the top of app.py, 
after in some_update() we add:
    current_url = request.url
    global url
    url = current_url
and final in post_new() we add:
    calls_df = pd.read_html(url)

For our app it's work correct!!!
Thank you!